# Testing filepicker.io security using Ruby

Tags: ruby, filepicker.io

I'm trying to build a test that will allow me to exercise FilePicker.io security.  The code is run as:

```
ruby test.rb [file handle]
```

and the result is the query string that I can append to a FilePicker URL.  I'm pretty sure my policy is getting read properly, but my signature isn't.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Here's the code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'base64'
require 'cgi'
require 'openssl'
require 'json'

handle = ARGV[0]
expiry = Time::now.to_i + 3600
policy = {:handle=>handle, :expiry=>expiry, :call=>["pick","read", "stat"]}.to_json
puts policy
puts "\n"
secret = 'SECRET'
encoded_policy = CGI.escape(Base64.encode64(policy))
signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('sha256', secret, encoded_policy)
puts "?signature=#{signature}&policy=#{encoded_policy}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to use Base64.urlsafe_encode64 instead of CGI.escape:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'base64'
require 'cgi'
require 'openssl'
require 'json'

handle = ARGV[0]
expiry = Time::now.to_i + 3600
policy = {:handle=>handle, :expiry=>expiry}.to_json
puts policy
puts "\n"
secret = 'SECRET'
encoded_policy = Base64.urlsafe_encode64(policy)
signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('sha256', secret, encoded_policy)
puts "?signature=#{signature}&policy=#{encoded_policy}"
```

When tested with the sample values for expiry, handle, and secret in the Filepicker.io docs it returns same values as the python example.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear I was in Ruby 1.8 at this time, so I don't have access to that method.  I did solve the problem by removing the CGI.escape and gsubbing out the newlines.  I'm not sure if that's correct strictly speaking, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this in my Ruby 1.8 environment by removing the CGI.escape and gsubbing out the newline:

```
 Base64.encode64(policy).gsub("\n","")
```

elevenarms's answer is the best for Ruby 1.9 users, but you have to do something a bit kludgy like the above for Ruby 1.8.  I'll accept his answer nonetheless, since most of us are or shortly will be in 1.9 these days.